# string_agg function with Condition

Tags: postgresql

My query

```
Select ID,string_agg(doc_id,',') from table group by ID;
```

This gives me

```
ID       DOC_ID
123      01,02,03
456      01
789      02
100      01,03
```

Now I don't want data with doc_id as 01 and 02. But if 01 and 02 comes along with other doc_id, then I want that in my out

Now when I am running

```
Select ID,string_agg(doc_id,',') from table group by ID,doc_id having doc_id not in (02,03) ;
```

Its giving me nothing, whereas I am expecting

```
ID       DOC_ID
123      01,02,03
100      01,03
```

so how to give condition with string agg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of potential ways...

First, just eliminate any result where the aggregate is only '01' or '02':

```
select
  id, string_agg (doc_id, ',')
from table
group by id
having
  array_agg (doc_id) not in ('{01}', '{02}')
```

Or, you can use other logic, like if the count is more than 1 (therefore it can't **only** be '01' or '02') *OR* the single result is not '01' or '02':

```
select
  id, string_agg (doc_id, ',')
from table
group by id
having
  count (*) > 1 or
  min (doc_id) not in ('01', '02')
```

The 'min' works because at this point when count > 1 fails, you know you only have a single element...  so a min will be the result of that one element.